# Fatal Error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) on line 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, numbers, codeigniter-3

I am getting this error in codeigniter 3.
I had tried most of the things but none of them worked.

```
    function money_format($num = 0, $pro = 2)
    {
        %number =round((float)$num, $pro);

         if($pro == 2)
            $num = money_format("%!^2n",(float)$num);
         else
            $num = money_format("%=*!^.".$pro."n",(float)$num);
         return $num;
     )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Increase `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` file. If this is not resolving the issues:

**2) Add this line `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` before the line where you get the error**

Answer (score 2):

This is a recursive function without a stop condition. This will lead to an infinite loop. It'll always calls itself until there is no memory left.

If I could suggest an alternative, I would say to use the number_format function to format numbers. Its a native php function and really simple to use. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).